# SELECT Multiple Images URL and load in Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to PHP programming and I need someone help now. I have 2 tables. In table 2 I have image links stored like

```
id           image URL     order
12345   www.abc.com/xxx.jpg 0
12345   www.abc.com/yyy.jpg 1
12346   www.abc.com/zzz.jpg 0
12346   www.abc.com/aaa.jpg 1
12346   www.abc.com/vvv.jpg 2
12346   www.abc.com/333.jpg 3
12347   www.abc.com/vvf.jpg 0
12347   www.abc.com/111.jpg 1
```

In table 1

```
id         name
12345   something1
12346   something2
12347   something3
.   
.
```

I have to load the data after LEFT JOIN with table 1 with key **Id**.  Assume table1 have 7 variables too.the output I need is

```
id  name(table1)    img1(oforder0)  img2(oforder1)  img3(of order2) img4(oforder3)
12345   something1  www.abc.com/xxx.jpg www.abc.com/yyy.jpg -   -
12346   something2  www.abc.com/zzz.jpg www.abc.com/aaa.jpg     www.abc.com/vvv.jpg www.abc.com/333.jpg
12347   something 3 www.abc.com/vvf.jpg www.abc.com/111.jpg -   -
```

is it possible to do first of all? All I have tried until now is put **for** loop for image names & using Where order='$i' and create own variables and that’s doesn’t seems to work.
 Because I don’t want the id and name field repeat again and again.I need someone help here to choose the right way to get the URL in the same row(if it is possible)

Comment: Is the number of images exactly 3 or <= 3, or is it variable/unknown, possibly > 3?

Comment: It _is_ possible and there are 2 ways to approach it depending on the answer to my 1st question.

Comment: Micheal,i have  upto 11 images in the database for each id. all i need is 4 images URL.

Comment: So you want _only_ items 0-3 for each `id`, though you may have more?

Comment: yes thats right ! is it possible mate! i get stuck here for more than 8 hours micheal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exactly 4 out of 11 image urls you can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.order = 0 THEN image_url END) img1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.order = 1 THEN image_url END) img2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.order = 2 THEN image_url END) img3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.order = 3 THEN image_url END) img4
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id 
  GROUP BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
|    ID |       NAME |                IMG1 |                IMG2 |                IMG3 |                IMG4 |
|-------|------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 12345 | something1 | www.abc.com/xxx.jpg | www.abc.com/yyy.jpg |              (null) |              (null) |
| 12346 | something2 | www.abc.com/zzz.jpg | www.abc.com/aaa.jpg | www.abc.com/vvv.jpg | www.abc.com/333.jpg |
| 12347 | something3 | www.abc.com/vvf.jpg | www.abc.com/111.jpg |              (null) |              (null) |
```

---

An alternative solution might be to pack all image urls into one column (let's call it urls) per id  using `GROUP_CONCAT()` like this

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t2.order + 1, '|', t2.image_url) ORDER BY t2.order) urls
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id 
   AND t2.order <= 3
  GROUP BY t1.id
```

and then `explode` (split) `urls` values first by comma `,` then by a pipe `|` while you're iterating over the resultset.

**Note:** This approach is more dynamic. You can easily change how many image urls you want without changing the query itself.

Output:

```
|    ID |       NAME |                                                                                    URLS |
|-------|------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 12345 | something1 |                                             1|www.abc.com/xxx.jpg,2|www.abc.com/yyy.jpg |
| 12346 | something2 | 1|www.abc.com/zzz.jpg,2|www.abc.com/aaa.jpg,3|www.abc.com/vvv.jpg,4|www.abc.com/333.jpg |
| 12347 | something3 |                                             1|www.abc.com/vvf.jpg,2|www.abc.com/111.jpg |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ae8b/3)** demo

Comment: You can have my SQLfiddle. I was in the middle of a longer explanation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've almost done with mine (sqlfiddle), but thank you very much :)

Comment: i will do the query now and i will let you the output asap!! thanks for your help